# The array reassignment in the following c++ function seems to have been ignored after the function call.

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters

```
void func(int* array)
{
    array=new int[5];
    for (int i=5; i>0; i--)
        array[5-i]=i;
}
int main()
{
    int array[5]= {1,2,3,4,5};
    func(array);
    cout<<array[1]<<endl;
}
```

I presume this has something to do with arrays being constant pointers. How exactly does c++ handle this code and what happens to the dynamic memory that is assigned within the function?

Comment: Arrays are definitely not constant pointers. You also set the copy of the pointer that the array you passed in **decayed** into to new memory (which you don't free), so how would it affect the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an array as argument to a function *by value*, it decays to the pointer to the first element, which then gets passed *by value*. So what you recieve in the function `func` is a *copy* of the address of the first element of the array. In the function, you simply change the address, which doesn't change the array in the `main()` function. Whatever you do to `array` in `func()`, is **local** to that function only. It is like this:

```
void f(int x)
{
     x= 100; //modifying the copy, not the variable in main()
}
int main()
{
     int value = 1000;
     f(x); //pass by value, means pass a copy!
}
```

In this case you're changing the value of `x` in `f()`. Likewise, in your case, you're changing the value of `array`. **Since `array` is a pointer, you're making it pointing to a different location by allocating a new memory to it.**  Every change is local to the function.

Also note that since you allocate memory to the variable `array`, and don't deallocate it, your program **leaks memory**. In order to avoid that, you must write:

```
 delete [] array;
```

before returning from the function. Again, this `delete` wouldn't change `array` in `main()`.

By the way, if you want to change the element of the array in `main()`, then you should do this instead:

```
void func(int* array)
{
    //array=new int[5]; //just comment this
    for (int i=5; i>0; i--)
        array[5-i]=i; //now array points to the same memory 
                      //where main()'s array is in the memory.
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You should probably mention he could have just taken out the `array=new int[5];` line to get what he wanted (presumably) here. (Although that's slightly unclear since he does mention dynamic memory, so who knows?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
array=new int[5];
```

This assignment means that the passed parameter will not be modified. After this assignment, `array` points to a newly allocated chunk of memory rather than to the `array` declared in `main` (and passed to `func` as an argument). What is modified is this newly allocated array -- and that's thrown away when the function returns. To make matters worse, you have a memory leak.

Comment: It's not a declaration, and I don't think the compiler would have warned about this, no matter the warning level.

Comment: You're right, both of you. This is an assignment, not a declaration. Nonetheless, this assignment statement is the source of the problem.